# caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') on Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to plot a OHLC chart with react and typescript using this code.

```
import { ApexOptions } from "apexcharts";
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

interface OhlcData {
  timestamp: string;
  open: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  close: number;
}

interface Props {
  data: OhlcData[];
}

const CandleChart: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data, 'Data in the chart')
const options: ApexOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: "candlestick",
    height: 350,
    id: "ohlc-chart",
    toolbar: {
      autoSelected: "zoom",
      show: false
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yaxis: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
      colors: {
        upward: "#4CAF50",
        downward: "#F44336"
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: data.map((d) => ({
        x: new Date(d.timestamp).getTime(),
        y: [d.open, d.high, d.low, d.close]
      }))
    }
  ]
};
return <Chart options={options} />
};

export default CandleChart;
```

And receiving this error:

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Function.value (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14:1)
    at t.create (apexcharts.common.js:6:1)
    at apexcharts.common.js:14:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t.value (apexcharts.common.js:14:1)
    at apexcharts.common.js:14:1
```

The data is going through:

```
[{"open":0.5,"high":0.5,"low":0.5,"close":0.5,"timestamp":1681743362000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681758826000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681758886000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681758950000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759013000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759075000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759136000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759197000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759266000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759328000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681759396000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760395000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760463000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760531000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760602000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760674000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760744000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760805000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760865000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760932000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681760997000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761063000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761123000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761187000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761255000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761328000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761395000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761457000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761589000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761659000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761721000},{"open":0.00003,"high":0.00003,"low":0.00003,"close":0.00003,"timestamp":1681761783000}]
```

Can someone advice on this error? Is there anything wrong with the imports maybe? At the moment i don't have a single hint. Tryed help from chatGPT but it couldn't help me.